# How to make a property unique in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

This is my `User` model Class:

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Remote("IsUsernameExists", "Home", HttpMethod = "Post")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 18, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is `IsUsernameExists` method in `Home` controller

```
public JsonResult IsUsernameExists(string UserName)
{            
    return Json(!db.Users.Any(x => x.Username == UserName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any further help will highly be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: nothing happen. when i enter a username that already exists it will go to database and record it

Comment: Try to use `x => x.Username == UserName.ToLowerInvariant()` and let me know if it works!

Comment: still nothing happened

Comment: Your `UserName` might contains spaces also. You can also try the `Trim` method after `ToLower` method and see if it works!

Comment: you mean this ?            x => x.Username == UserName.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()    if that it doesn't work again

Comment: @GregH The method (`IsUsernameExists`) that is posted in the question is used for *RemoteVaidation* and there is no need to be marked as Post.

Comment: @farshidtorkaman, Dear I posted an answer to your question taking some times! You didn't tell whether it had worked for you or not! If you just ignore after getting the answer then how will the people get inspired to help you again? Thank you.

Comment: actually i did read everyone answers. but when you post your asnwer i find the solution. and i didn't try your solution. i'm sorry for not answering.

Comment: @farshidtorkaman Okay! I have seen your own answer! This is not the best way to do these things! May be it solve your problem for the time being but not the good practice. Read my answer thoroughly it will help you to understand these things clearly. Good Luck!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I create a method in HomeController

```
   public bool IsUserExist(string email)
   {
        return db.Users.Where(c => c.Email == email).IsAny();
   }
```

and in Action

```
    if( IsUserExist(model.Email) )
    {
        // my code
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a model property `Unique` by using Both `DataAnnotation` and `FluentApi` as follows:

### Using Data Annotation:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(30)]
[Index("Ix_UserName",Order =1,IsUnique =true)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

### Using Fluent Api:

**In Entity Framework >= 6.2,**

In `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(30);
     modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.UserName).IsUnique();
}
```

**In Entity Framework < 6.2**

In `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.UserName).HasMaxLength(30)
                                  .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("Ix_UserName"){IsUnique = true}));
}
```

**Remember:** With `Index` attribute you must have to use `StringLength` attribute also.

For making `RemoteAttibute` working, write your  `RemoteAttibute` on `UserName` property as follows:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(30)]
[Index("Ix_UserName",Order =1,IsUnique =true)]
[Remote("IsUserNameExist", "Home", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "User Name already exists")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And then the `IsUserNameExist` method in the `HomeController` as follows:

```
public JsonResult IsUserNameExist(string UserName, int? Id)
{
     var IsUserNameExists = db.Users.Any(x => x.UserName== UserName && x.Id != Id);
     return Json(!IsUserNameExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Finally ensure that your view contains the following `jQuery` files:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-version.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Everything should work now fine!

Answer (score 1):

The [RemoteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) doesn't have anything to do with Entity Framework. It simply ignores this attribute. Furthermore, as the documentation says, it's a `jQuery` validation attribute, it's supposed to work on front end part only.

If `User` is both MVC model and database entity, you should create a unique index for the property. One way to do that is in `OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(x => new { x.Username }).IsUnique();
}
```

Then create a migration, apply it to the database and you're good to go. However, be aware of the exception you will get when saving duplicates and make sure you handle it properly.